# Calculation of Average Due Date with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to calculate Average Due Date and Balance for each customer. I have two tables, first one is Customer List Table, second one is Pay Transactions.

Table A (lG_060_CLCARD) - Customer List

```
LOGICALREF  DEFINITION_
------------------------
18166       ABC INC
```

Table B (LG_060_04_PAYTRANS) - PAY TRANSACTIONS

```
CARDREF      PROCDATE     SIGN   TOTAL   DISCDUEDATE
-----------------------------------------------------
18166       2020.03.21     1     1000     2020.03.21
18166       2020.03.21     1     15000    2020.03.21
18166       2020.02.29     0     2500     2020.03.30
18166       2020.02.29     0     6000     2020.03.30
18166       2020.03.16     0     4000     2020.04.15
18166       2020.03.16     0     6500     2020.04.15
18166       2020.03.16     0     2000     2020.05.15
```

Explanation of second table: this customer (18166) paid to me twice (`SIGN` means paid to me if equals 1) on 21th March 2020 which is 1000 + 15000 = 16000. Same customer bought 5 different items on 2 different days. Their Due Date shown in `DISCDUEDATE` column.

Manual calculation of Average Due Date:

Table B (LG_060_04_PAYTRANS) - PAY TRANSACTIONS

```
CARDREF      PROCDATE     SIGN   TOTAL   DISCDUEDATE   *cumulativeBalance
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
18166       2020.03.21     1     1000     2020.03.21    -1000
18166       2020.03.21     1     15000    2020.03.21    -16000
18166       2020.02.29     0     2500     2020.03.30    -13500
18166       2020.02.29     0     6000     2020.03.30    -7500
18166       2020.03.16     0     4000     2020.04.15    -3500
18166       2020.03.16     0     6500     2020.04.15    3000 --> balance turns into positive
18166       2020.03.16     0     2000     2020.05.15
```

Calculation starts with sixth row, because balance turns into positive with this row. And we use 3000 instead of 6500 for sixth row.

Calculation Table should be like:

```
CARDREF      PROCDATE     SIGN   TOTAL   DISCDUEDATE   DAY
-----------------------------------------------------------
18166       2020.03.16     0     3000     2020.04.15   2
18166       2020.03.16     0     2000     2020.05.15   32
```

DAY means difference between today and Due Date `DISCDUEDATE`. Today is 2020.04.13

So, Average Due Date (ADD) is;

```
2 x 3000  = 6000
32 x 2000 = 64000
          +--------
            68000

ADD = 68000 : (3000+2000) = 13,6 = 13 days
```

The real problem for me is to calculate balance amount and date which turns into positive (positive balance date and amount). After that day, all positive rows (SIGN=0) should be added in calculation.

I have some code for this calculation.

```
SELECT
    CL.DEFINITION_,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SIGN=1 THEN -1 WHEN SIGN=0 THEN 1 END * TOTAL) AS BALANCE,
    FLOOR(SUM(DUEDATE)/SUM(TOTAL)) AS 'AVG DATE',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY, FLOOR(SUM(DUEDATE)/SUM(TOTAL)), GETDATE()),104) AS 'AVG DUE DATE'
FROM
    LG_060_CLCARD CL
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
         CARDREF, SIGN, TOTAL,
         (DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(),DISCDUEDATE) * TOTAL) AS DUEDATE
     FROM
         LG_060_04_PAYTRANS
     WHERE
         CANCELLED = 0) PT ON PT.CARDREF = LOGICALREF
WHERE
    LOGICALREF = 18166
GROUP BY
    CL.DEFINITION_, CL.LOGICALREF
```

This code works well, it calculates balance correctly but it calculates average day and average due date wrongly. Because I don't know how to calculate positive balance date and amount?

Answer (score 0):

I built a similar table to yours called "payt" and with tsql the following works. I added a cardref to be sure the code still works when there are more cardref:

```
/*
create table payt (
      cardref int,
      procdate date,
      sign int,
      total float,
      discduedate date);


    insert into payt values (18166,'2020-03-21',1,1000,'2020-03-21'),
                              (18166,'2020-03-21',1,15000,'2020-03-21'),
                              (18166,'2020-02-29',0,2500,'2020-03-30'),
                              (18166,'2020-02-29',0,6000,'2020-03-30'),
                              (18166,'2020-03-16',0,4000,'2020-04-15'),
                              (18166,'2020-03-16',0,6500,'2020-04-15'),
                              (18166,'2020-03-16',0,2000,'2020-05-15'),
                              (18164,'2020-03-16',1,600,'2020-04-16'),
                              (18164,'2020-03-16',0,2000,'2020-05-10')
    */
    select *,
    case when sign=1 then -total else total end as num,
    row_number() over (partition by cardref order by discduedate) as r1
    into #t1
    from payt

    declare @c as int=(select min(cardref) from payt)
    declare @m as int=(select max(cardref) from payt)


    select *,0 as dd
    into #t2
    from payt
    where cardref<@c

    while @c<=@m
    begin
    declare @r as int=0
    declare @s as int=-1

    while @s<0
    begin
    set @r=@r+1
    set @s=(select sum(num) as num
    from #t1
    where r1<=@r
    and cardref=@c)
    end

    insert into #t2
    select a.cardref,a.procdate,a.sign,
    case when a.r1=@r then @s else a.num end as total,
    a.discduedate,
    datediff(day,getdate(),a.discduedate) as dd
    from #t1 a
    where a.r1>=@r
    and a.cardref=@c

    set @c=(select min(cardref) from payt where cardref>@c)
    end

    select *
    from #t2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have some important data and dont want to take a risk due to my less sql knowledge. Could you please reorganise code without insert codes. Just taking information from server without sending it.

Comment: i commented the create statement and the insert statement you don't need. the remaining part should work, you just have to put the right name of the table instead of "party"